# MongoDb Atlas failed to connect to server [123:27017] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB in MongoDB Atlas, but I'm receing this error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [123:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.0.123:27017 - Local (192.168.15.6:56553)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/filipeferminiano/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/filipeferminiano/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/filipeferminiano/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  name: 'MongoError',
```

This is my code:

```
var db;
var mongoServer = 'mongodb://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@roas-shard-00-00-r4v7u.mongodb.net:27017,roas-shard-00-01-r4v7u.mongodb.net:27017,roas-shard-00-02-r4v7u.mongodb.net:27017/[DATABASE]?ssl=true&replicaSet=roas-shard-0&authSource=admin'.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

MongoClient.connect(mongoServer, (err, database) => {
   if (err) return console.log(err)
      db = database
      app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})
```

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? How are those hostnames resolving? Did you edit your own `/etc/hosts` or something? I see `0.0.0.123:27017` as a resolved address in the error, but these should all be resolving from DNS. Also that's a lot of hosts. You should really only need a limited number of seeds in a replica set connection rather than **all** the nodes. The **driver** will look after resolving all the nodes, so you don't need to specify them all. Try a `ping` on each hostname in the string. That will point to which ( if not many ) are causing the problem.

Comment: Also the `27017` port is "default". So if this is the port in use, then you do not need to specify explicitly on each host. Just use the hostname without the port.